# Accessing multiple databases with identical schemata

Tags: .net, sql-server, wcf, entity-framework, multi-tenant

I've got to implement a system where there are several (no fixed limit) databases or schemas with identical tables structures for a [multitenancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy) system.

For each request, some sort of database/schema ID (like a tenant ID) is provided.
What I'd like to do is to select the database or schema based on that ID and tell my entity framework model (code first) to target that particular database/schema.
Then the system, a WCF service, will do a few queries and wait for the next call, targeting (likely) another database/schema.
Naturally, several requests may be executed at the same time in different threads, accessing different databases/schemata using entity objects.

I'm using SQL Server and the number of tenants will likely be between about 5 and 50.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Btw, is there a difference in SQL Server between schema and database? I know there is with oracle but I'm pretty new to SQL Server and don't fully understand all the microsoft terminology yet.

Lots of Greetings!
Volker

Comment: A [SQL Server] database can have multiple schemas. Schemas provide logical grouping, often for security/roles, of objects within a single database. It's often confusing to talk about "schemas" at the same time as talking about the "database schema" ..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's entirely possible.

`DbContext`, from which your context will inherit, has a constructor which receives a ConnectionString name (declared in your web.config) or the actual ConnectionString. So you can dynamically build the connectionString and connect to different databases using the same Context type.

However, consider that you would create a Context instance, you would not use the same Context instance for more than one database at the same time.

Now, in your scenario, you'd have to think about how you will resolve some specific id to an actual database name. You could do that by having an extra database, like a master database that will hold that information.

**NOTE:** Be careful if you're going to be using EF Migrations. Be sure to be applying the migrations to the correct database.

Answer (score 0):

Using the DbContext's OnModelCreatining event you may set the default schema.

Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-schema

In combination with a custom ConnectionString builder you may achieve your task.